# How do I add an image to a new Listview Item?

Tags: vb.net, image, listview

```
Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
dis = dr("Last Accessed").Substring(0, dr("Last Accessed").IndexOf(" "))
ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {docImage, dr("Id").ToString, dr("Document Name").ToString, dr("DISnummer"), dr("XPostnummer"), dis}))
```

I use this code to fill a listview but I like to add a little image to the left of the rows. I connected an imagelist but the code for adding the image doesnt work:

```
If dr("[Document Type]").ToString = "PDF" Or dr("[Document Type]").ToString = "pdf" Then
   docImage = (ImageList1.Images.Count - 1)
Endif
```

What am I doing wrong?

M

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I figured it out.

```
While dr.Read
            If dr("Document Type").ToString = "PDF" Or dr("Document Type").ToString = "pdf" Then
                docImage = (ImageList1.Images.Count - 1)
            ElseIf dr("Document Type").ToString = "DOC" Or dr("Document Type").ToString = "doc" Then
                docImage = (ImageList1.Images.Count - 3)
            ElseIf dr("Document Type").ToString = "PPT" Or dr("Document Type").ToString = "ppt" Then
                docImage = (ImageList1.Images.Count - 2)
            End If

            dis = dr("Last Accessed").Substring(0, dr("Last Accessed").IndexOf(" "))
            items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {"", dr("Document Name").ToString, dr("DISnummer"), dr("XPostnummer"), dis, dr("Id").ToString, dr("Document Location").ToString}, docImage))
        End While
```

The image is at the end of the items.Add function

Comment: After a bit of time you can accept your own answer. I won't earn you any points but it will help future readers.